# Custom trigger showing up in Google Analytics - but NOT the value itself

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have a gtag account setup and that also connects to google analytics. 
And I have made a successful tag/trigger to make event tracking for when an FAQ item is opened at [my clients FAQ-page](https://captumgroup.se/kundservice/)

I am sending the trigered FAQ question text as a value as well. And I wish to have a list in Google Analytics in which the questions are shown in a list.

Am I missing something? Should I setup the trigger/tag in another way, or am I missing something in the GA.

Thanks for taking your time.

**DEBUGGER**
[image]

**TAG CONFIGURATION:**
[image]

**GA:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The event value in Google Analytics [must be a number](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev). You are currently passing {{Click Text}} string, which actually gets ignored by ga object, and will not reach Google Analyitics. [More details on event tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en).

Basically, you should send this text data in a text field into Analytics.

**Original recommendation, using custom dimensions:**

I recommend you to set up a hit based custom dimension, where you can submit additional text data in connection to your event. You'll be able to analyze it as a secondary dimension in standard event reports, or by creating custom reports.

In GTM, you have to modify either the Google Analytics setting variable, or the Analytics tag itself, and assign the desired value (click text in your case) to the custom dimension ID, which you have created in Google Analytics. E.g. custom dimension 6 gets passed like this:
[image]

**An other option, based on Eike's suggestion:**

You can also use any of the other standard event fields for this, e.g. send it in the label. As pointed out, this can even hold larger set of data (500 bytes), compared to custom dimensions (150 bytes). This is also easier to be implemented in GA and GTM as well, as you don't have to deal with custom dimension creation and reporting.

Comment: Beat me to it. However I would rather use the event label for the question (unless they are all very short), because the label holds 500 bytes, and a custom dimension only 150. And really, setting "question" as label does not add much value.

Comment: Hi! I have implemented the "easy fix" as @EikePierstorff recommended. Setting the label to the "question". Label = {{Click Text}}.

This would do it I thought. And in Behavior > Events in GA there is a possibility to add "Secondary dimension" to show all labels clicked on in the category of FAQ etc. 

Not sure how optimal this is. But in the case of your solution kgrg - I was not thrilled about adding a numerical index as an extra layer of abstraction - even though it might have advantages.

Comment: I would suggest that @kgrg edits my comment into his answer and you accept it, since he identified the basic issue and I just added an implementation detail.